# XNZVC Operation (Assembly Language Easy68K)

Tags: assembly, easy68k

**If  = $025C3F90, XNZVC=00011, what’s the results in D0 and in CCR?
MOVE.W  #$8C,D0**

What is the D0 and CCR? 
How do we add 90 to 8C technically

Answer (score 1):

> How do we add 90 to 8C technically

The instruction in your question is a `move.w`, which does replacement, not addition.  The `w` stands for `word`, which on the 68k is 16 bits. Using a `word` sized operation, it is loading an immediate value into a register.

> What is the D0?

`d0.w` gets replaced with `0x008c`,

which means that `d0.l` is then `0x025C008c`.

> and the CCR?

Condition codes:

```
X N Z V C
- * * 0 0
```

So, `N` & `Z` are set by the value of the `word` that was moved, which was `0x008c`; while `V` & `C` are cleared, and `X` is unmodified.